# How can I return Level Property values in an MDX query?

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

I've defined a Dimension in a schema file containing multiple Levels. One of my Levels contains multiple properties, like:

```
<Level name="MyLevel" column="MyLevelColumn" nameColumn="MyLevelName">
    <Property name="Property1" column="PropertyColumn1"/>
    <Property name="Property2" column="PropertyColumn2"/>
    <Property name="Property3" column="PropertyColumn3"/>
    <Property name="Property4" column="PropertyColumn4"/>
</Level>
```

How can I return the values of these Properties, as well as the values of the measures I've defined in my Schema file?

Note: I don't want to use these filters to filter my results in the MDX query, so if there's a better way to get the data I want, please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about Pentaho (couldn't find any MDX docs in a brief search of their site), but in SSAS, you can do the following:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Property1] AS 
    ([MyDim].[MyLevel].CurrentMember.Properties("Property1"))
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Property1], [Measures].[Amount]}
ON COLUMNS,
    {[MyDim].[MyLevel].MEMBERS}
ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

Comment: In case it's of any use here's the link: http://mondrian.pentaho.org/documentation/mdx.php